# When Pointing From http//www To https//www Appear Redirect Loop

Tags: apache, ubuntu, redirect, https

I have some strange issue related to the redirect loop appearing.

For example, my website begin with `https://www` in the WordPress website general setting I have the same address that is begin with: `https://www`

also in this file 000-default.conf (folder site enabled) I have those lines:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVERNAME} =www.test.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVERNAME} =test.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVERNAME}%{REQUESTURI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

and in the .httaces file, I have nothing.

But when I enter to the browser website that begins with this one `http://www` I have those redirect chains:

`http://www` 301 redirect to `https://` 301 redirect to `https://www`

Somebody could help how to avoid the second unnecessary chain element in order to get the redirect from `http://www` directly here: `https://www`

The best option is to set-up redirect from all those options:

`http://www.
http://
https://`

to `https://www.`

---

I find a solution - to use this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVERNAME} =www.test.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVERNAME} =test.org
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

So i checked all redirect scenario:

```
http://www.test.org/ - redirect here https://www.test.org/
http://test.org/ - redirect here https://www.test.org/
https://test.org/ - don`t redirect here https://www.test.org/
https://www.test.org/ - is ok
So as you see this url: https://test.org/ don`t redirect here: https://www.test.org/
```

Also actually I don`t know related it to this code or not, but also I use the special redirection plugin called "Redirection" for WordPress - I set-upped 301 redirect from the / - main page to another website.

And interesting thing - when I delete this redirect via redirection plugin all seems that works well and all redirection scenaria works well, but when I use the redirection plugin only this one scenario:

`` https://test.org/ - don`t redirect here https://www.test.org/ ``

don`t work.

Tell, please should we customize the code that I provided or the problem in this "Redirection" plugin and could you help with this issue?

Many thanks